# What is Wijmo License and why am I being asked to create one?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am coding a Jupyter Notebook on VSCode using the Jupyter extension. Just now, this issue has arised (apparently my license expired?). Every time I click on a .csv file, to view my submission for Kaggle, I get this pop-up. I have no idea what Wijmo is and I don't recall downloading anything relating to it or licensing.

[Pop-Up that appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8meY.png)

I looked it up but there is almost no info online about this thing and the only other page I saw is from a few days ago asking a similar question, but no answers. How can I remove it / do I have to get this license? It's not problematic as I can just close the pop-up but it is pretty annoying.

Comment: what did you google? I just googled `wijmo license` and the top result was https://www.grapecity.com/wijmo/licensing. What extension are you using that displays csv files like that? That's the probably a start on figuring out where the issue is coming from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are using "Excel Viewer" extension by Grape City.

For whatever reason, they are asking for a license since 25/03/23.

I would normally assume dodgy practise by the developer of the extension, by the way of continually using trial licenses or maybe their own license just expired.

Looking at the changelog of the extension, it looks like they regularly have to update the license by way of an update.

> **4.2.56 (September 20, 2022) Updated Wijmo license. No other changes.**
>
> 4.2.55 (June 13, 2022) Fixed issue with CSV editing where text pasted into a cell was ignored when saving the file.
>
> Fixed issue with CSV editing where changing a value in the rightmost
> cell could result in extra line breaks and/or misaligned cells when
> saving the file.
>
> Fixed issue where a line number was displayed instead of the *
> character in the AddNew row.
>
> 4.2.54 (March 29, 2022) Fixed problems with CSV editing when the csv-preview.separator configuration setting was set to a regular
> expression instead of a single character.
>
> **4.2.53 (March 9, 2022) Updated Wijmo license to remove nag screen.**
>
> Editing features for CSV/Excel files are now part of the stable
> version.

Below is a github issue relating to this.

https://github.com/jjuback/gc-excelviewer/issues/219

Comment: Grapecity won't sue itself for the alleged violation of their own product's license, but another corporation might for a different reason... The name "Excel" itself is a trademark of MSFT Corp... ("Microsoft(R) Excel (R)")

Answer (score 0):

In VS Code you can uninstall and reinstall the extension and it appears to be just fine. Not sure that is the way you want to go but I prefer it.